# Proving there is an assymptotical solution when Jacobian at singularity has a negative eigenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Consider the ODE $x'(t)=f(x(t))$ (in an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$) with a singularity at $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to prove that if the jacobian matrix $A=f'(x_0)$ has an eigenvalue with negative real part, then there is a non-trivial solution such that $\lim_{t\to+\infty}x(t)=x_0$.

If $A$ is hyperbolic (all eigenvalue have non-zero real part), it follows from the Hartman-Grobman Theorem.

What if it isn't hyperbolic?

I know that $-f(x_0)$ will have an eigenvalue with positive real part, and from this we can conclude $x_0$ is an unstable singularity of the ODE $x'(t)=-f(x(t))$ (which has the same solutions with inverted direction).

I was trying to show that this (being unstable with respect to $-f$), is sufficient for existing a solution as wanted, but couldn't prove it (and don't even know if it is true). (Edit: it is not true)

How could I procede?

Comment: It was suposed to be a non-trivial solution. Edited it, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps there's more down-to-earth way of showing it, but part of the **center manifold theorem** (see, for example, Theorem 3.2.1 in [Guckenheimer & Holmes](https://www.amazon.com/Nonlinear-Oscillations-Dynamical-Bifurcations-Mathematical/dp/0387908196)) is that there is a nontrivial stable manifold if there are eigenvalues with negative real part.

Comment: @HansLundmark The book this exercise is from doesn't mention this theorem (nor defines manifolds), so the author probably thought about some solution, but this will do for the next time I study ODE's again (the course just finished). Thanks.